# How do I get react router path with params?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am trying to get the current matching path in react application without parameters but could not.

For example:

```
<Route path="/portal/dashboard/searchResults/:assetType/:searchQuery?" 
  component={DataCatalogSearchResult}
  ></Route>
```

I want "portal/dashboard/searchResults" in my component. I have tried using useLocation() hook but it gives me full address with params. How do I exclude params from access the base URL?

Comment: You can either get the path params, i.e. `assetType` and `searchQuery`, or the entire `path` path pattern that is used for matching and nested routes, or the entire `url` that used for nested links. See [match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match). What is the use-case you are trying to solve for?

Comment: @DrewReese Usecase: Whenever DataCatalogSearchResult component renders I want to access the current URL but without params. In my case it would be "portal/dashboard/searchResults"

Comment: You know what that "base URL" is at compile time when you define the route's path, refactor code a bit and pass as a prop, i.e. via the route's `render` prop.